# ANy experiences with DropboxSync by jessegrosjean?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

While looking for sample code for Dropbox integration, i happened on this:

https://github.com/jessegrosjean/DropboxSync

This seems like just the ticket for me. All I want is to keep one dedicated folder of RTF files in synch with a dedicated folder on the user's account. Looks too good to be true. Is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Request for an folder only API and not the all access version 
Then DropboxSnync as well as chdropboxsync and all the other forks keep it in sync

So yes it is like it looks like